# Breadth first search query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, graph

I want to build a mySQL query, which returns all nodes in a graph in x depth from a given node. The depth will be only 2-4.

The table structure is (neighborIDs can contain multiple values):

```
Id  Name  Desc  neighborIDs
```

So the task is basically a Breadth-first search in mySQL. I have found a [way to do it in T-SQL](http://willets.org/sqlgraphs.html), is this possible in mySQL?
Is a single SQL query better, than writing a PHP function, that runs a simple SELECT on every neighbour of a node (so basically making tons of simple queries)?

Thanks for help

---

A try:

```
SELECT  root.ID,
        d1.ID,
        d2.ID
FROM    Locations root
        LEFT JOIN Locations d1 ON
          root.neighborIDs LIKE CONCAT('%',d1.id,'%')
        LEFT JOIN Locations d2 ON
          d1.neighborIDs LIKE CONCAT('%',d2.id,'%')
WHERE root.id = 1  # i guess this defines the starting node for the search..
```

An example table is:

```
id   name   desc                   neighborIDs  
1    id1    --     
2    id2    ---        
3    id3    neighborours are 1,2   1,2  
4    id4    neighbour is 3         3
10   id10   neigh is 4             4
```

If i run the query with the input id=1, it should return the row with id=3 if the BFS goes 1 level deep.

---

Another try:

```
SELECT id,neighborIDs
FROM locations
WHERE id = 3
OR
neighborIDs LIKE '%3%'
OR (SELECT neighborIDs FROM locations WHERE id = 3) LIKE CONCAT('%',id,'%')
```

This query selects the neighbors of the node with id = 3.

Comment: You've started out making your life difficult by putting multiple values into neighbourIDs. As a result, any solution requires decomposing the list, and restricts potential benefits from indexing.

Comment: Then how would you store neighbor IDs?

Comment: Using an association table. (Id, NeighbourId) Each neighbour is represented in a separate row. E.g. Using 'neighbour Integers': (1,0) (1,2) (2,1) (2,3) (3,2) (3,4) ...

Comment: @sydd: With the data you provide, it seems the graph is **directed**. @Craig: assumed you had an **undirected** graph (where if 1 is neighbour of 3, then 3 is neighbour 1 too).

Comment: @ypercube The graph is undirected, just its stored in this (bad) way. I cant change the DB layout unfortunately.

Comment: @So, you mean to find if 4 is a neighbour of 7, one has to search if both `4 is in 7.neighbours` and `7 is in 4.neighbours` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **step 0: Create a view that shows all neighbour pairs**

```
CREATE VIEW neighbour AS
( SELECT loc1.id AS a
       , loc2.id AS b
  FROM locations loc1
     , locations loc2
  WHERE FIND_IN_SET(loc1.id, loc2.neighbours)>0
     OR FIND_IN_SET(loc2.id, loc1.neighbours)>0
) ;
```

### **step 1: Find neighbours of depth 1**

```
SELECT b AS depth1
FROM neighbour
WHERE a = 1;               <-- for root with id=1
```

### **step 2: Find neighbours of depth 2**

```
SELECT DISTINCT d2.b AS depth2
FROM neighbour d1
  JOIN neighbour d2
    ON d1.b = d2.a
      AND d2.b != 1
WHERE d1.a = 1                <-- for root with id=1
  AND d2.b NOT IN
     ( SELECT b AS depth1     <- depth1 subquery
       FROM neighbour
       WHERE a = 1            <-- for root with id=1
      )
;
```

### **step 3: Find neighbours of depth 3**

```
SELECT d3.b as depth3
FROM neighbour d1
  JOIN neighbour d2
    ON d1.b = d2.a
    AND d2.b != 1
    AND d2.b NOT IN
       ( SELECT b as depth1
         FROM neighbour
         WHERE a = 1
       )
  JOIN neighbour d3
    ON d2.b = d3.a
    AND d3.b != 1
WHERE d1.a = 1
  AND d3.b NOT IN
     ( SELECT b as depth1
       FROM neighbour
       WHERE a = 1
      )
  AND d3.b NOT IN
     ( SELECT d2.b AS depth2
       FROM neighbour d1
         JOIN neighbour d2
           ON d1.b = d2.a
           AND d2.b != 1
       WHERE d1.a = 1
         AND d2.b NOT IN
            ( SELECT b AS depth1
              FROM neighbour
              WHERE a = 1
            )
     )
;
```

As you can see, the growth is exponential for the number of query lines, so I won't try the level 4.

Comment: woah so this really is a difficult question... ill try to understand it.

Comment: It's difficult because recursion is not easy to handle in SQL and certainly not in MySQL. Other RDBMS are better in this aspect.

Comment: But Craig's solution with the `LEFT JOIN`s is fairly good. It can be easily adapted to many levels as well. Only problem is that with many levels, there will be duplication or ids in the results, like the root id appearing in levels2 and deeper, depth1 ids appearing in level 2, etc.

Comment: It would be easier to write a `PROCEDURE` that handles such a search. And far more readable.

Comment: @sydd: Reading the article in the link you have (about a T-SQL solution), shows that indeed a procedure is far better for such problems. You can try to adapt one of those for MySQL. (you can use the `neighbour` view to have the graph in a more standard form than the original table.

Comment: @ypercube I've tried to write one, but gave up after one day, im not good at SQL

Comment: @ypercube your solution seems to work well, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, you've made your life difficult.
But something similar to the following will produce a list of neighbour IDs at each depth.
Depending on your exact needs, the result set can be used a subquery and manipulated further to necessary (such as retrieving the names of the neighbours).

```
SELECT  root.ID,
        d1.ID,
        d2.ID
FROM    Locations root
        LEFT JOIN Locations d1 ON
          root.Neighbours LIKE '%'+CAST(d1.ID as varchar)+'%'  --Or equivalent mysql pattern matching function
        LEFT JOIN Locations d2 ON
          d1.Neighbours LIKE '%'+CAST(d2.ID as varchar)+'%'
```

EDIT: Changed INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN

Comment: How does the Locations table look like? and the d1 and d2 tables?

Comment: You didn't name your table with (Id, Name, Desc, neighborIDs) so I called it `Locations`. `d1` and `d2` are not tables, they're aliases to reference the `Locations` table. This is needed because the query joins the `Locations` table back to itself, and without the aliases, the column references would be ambiguous. PS: It would be easy to repeat the pattern to drill down to a depth of 3 or 4.

Comment: I've tried to implement it and its not working. the query does not return nodes without children.

Comment: @sydd: turn thej `INNER JOIN`s into `LEFT JOIN`s.

Comment: @ypercube
Sorry, but thats not working either. For example my table is:

`id  name  desc                    neighborIDs
1  id1  --   
2  id2  ---   
3  id3  neighbor are_1,2    1,2
4  id4  neighb is_3            3`

My query is:
`SELECT  root.ID,
        d1.ID,
        d2.ID
FROM    Locations root
        LEFT JOIN Locations d1 ON
          root.neighborIDs LIKE CONCAT('%',d1.id,'%')
        LEFT JOIN Locations d2 ON
          d1.neighborIDs LIKE CONCAT('%',d2.id,'%')
WHERE root.id = 1`

  This returns one row (the one with id=1), but it should return the row with id=3 too.

Comment: @sydd: PLease post the above details by editing your question.

Comment: @ypercube i've done that now, and updated the query to use mySQL syntax

Comment: @sydd - don't edit other user's answers. If you have something new to add then update your question or answer separately if you've solved this using another user's help (and remember to attribute the post that helped).