# path finding via SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I've created a very large database and a beautiful and working app.
Everything is working as required/needed.
Now I want to select some items from a table from the database to put them in a custom recycler view I've implemented in my app. 
**So My question is:**
let this map of something.
[image]
And the table is as follows:
[image]
How one can achieve the following result using the table and using the input **2** and **E**.
 **2** - > **C** -> **D** -> **E**

Normally, whole line can be selected by using query like `select Name from table where line=1`.
**EDIT1** - 
You can find this example on [SQLFiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a24b96)

**EDIT2** -
As stated in a comment, I am not looking for a shortest path but a path where nothing appears more than once. You can understand this as Metro route example where one wants to know the route from A station to B station.
Length of routes is what I'll figure out later but now I want an idea(query) to get what I want. If you can suggest a way to implement both, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: You are looking for the shortest path in a non-oriented graph. Try A* or BFS.

Comment: Please suggest something, downvoting is not the needed answer.

Comment: I am not looking for a shortest path. You can understand this as Metro route example where one wants to know the route from A station to B station.

Comment: So a long route would be acceptable as well? Or just the first solution from among many?

Comment: Length of routes is what I'll figure out later but now I want an idea(query) to get what I want. If you can suggest a way to implement both, that would be appreciated as well.

Comment: This problem requires an algorithm, not a (single) query.

Comment: I want to get 2 -> C -> D-> E as result which is not the shortest but one without repeating nodes.

Comment: So would you suggest any algorithm or A* and BFS are the answer.

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357211/breadth-first-search-query-in-mysql?rq=1) what I need??

Comment: Please don't post images of data. People might want to play around with it, but not have to recreate it all. We want something we can copy from...In a perfect world you would create a http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Yes, you can research this yourself. You'll find it one of the 'hard' problems in computing.

Comment: @KikOSoftware Thank you for your precious time, I'll try.

Comment: @fancyPants I've added the sqlfiddle link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure whether your database structure is maintainable, seems to me that adding a station in the middle of somewhere would be a nightmare. The "is reachable from" information should not be implict in the indexes...

I rely on your assertion "I am not looking for a shortest path.", which I take as also implying that efficiency is generally not so important (otherwise use a programming language on top of SQL to implement one of the algorithms recommended in the comments). I.e. I do a reckless bruteforce concept.

So here is a proposal
(Note that this is SQLite, but I doubt that MySQL is unable to do any SQLite query
 and is not liked by the fiddle, I have troubles getting the fiddle to accept the recursion construct I am using...):

```
with reachable(fromname, toname)
as (
    select a.name, b.name
    from table1 a INNER JOIN table1 b
    on a.id+1 = b.id and a.color = b.color
    UNION ALL
    select a.name, b.name
    from table1 a INNER JOIN table1 b
    on a.id = b.id+1 and a.color = b.color
),
distance (name, dist, path)
as (
select 'E', 0, 'E'
UNION ALL
select a.fromname, b.dist+1, a.fromname||'->'||b.path
from reachable a INNER JOIN distance b
on a.toname = b.name and instr(b.path, a.fromname) =0
)
select path from distance where name = '2';
```

Details:

- make a reachable CTE, which station is directly reachable from which one,
  directional information, `with reachable ...`
- make a recursive CTE to determine path and distance,
  `with distance ...`
- concatenating the path
  `a.fromname||'->'||b.path`
- ignore stations which are already in the path
  `instr(b.path, a.fromname) =0`
- for each station (brute force)
- ignore stations which are already in the path
- start is in this code `where name = '2'`
- goal is, twice, here `select 'E', 0, 'E'`, the 0 is fixed

Output:

```
2->C->D->E
```

Tests:

- 2->E : `2->C->D->E`
- 4->E : `4->C->D->E`
- 4->B : `4->C->B`
- 2->B : `2->C->B`

Using: SQLite 3.18.0 2017-03-28

Comment: I can't able to execute it anywhere.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. You are using SQLite to do queries on a SQLite database, are you not? You should have the command line tool to play/experiment with pure SQLite syntax. Otherwise download it, it is free, free and very useful.

Comment: And you have a database?

Comment: Yes, I do, pretty large.

Comment: So open your database from the command line tool, and read a file with the proposed sql query. The dot-command `.read` does that for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153689/discussion-between-yunnosch-and-hardik-sharma).

Comment: In order to make sure you have the right tool, what is the output of your SQLite command line tool for `.version`?

Comment: I asked about the SQLite command line tool, using the word "SQLite" three times. You answered yes, meaning MySQL. I see.

Comment: Well, first lets try whether you can get your own fiddle to work. Copy the setup code from your fiddle and execute it to make a little toy database. Does that work? I did that with SQLite successfully, so it should be the common ground to work on.

Comment: I think this conversation is heading to nowhere. Sorry for wasting your time but I literally wanted to say this. Even I felt it what you wrote in your last reply.

Comment: As because of less knowledge of sql to understand you, it's not helping.

Comment: Problem is I can get my huge database to work with all the markers from it to display on map using latlong stored in database, or populating all the required listviews/recyclerviews from it but this is where I 'm stuck. And it's not working.

Comment: I'm glad you helped and upvoting and accepting your answer though I know nothing about it.